# YouTube Data API video insert/update - setting 'Game title'

Tags: api, video, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

The YouTube Data API v3 functions [`Video.insert`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) and [`Video.update`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/update) do not contain an option to set the "Game title" as you can when uploading / updating a video in the web UI:

[image: Game title]

This is only available if the category is set to `Gaming`.

Edit: To clarify, I do not wish to set the Video Title. This input is used to identify the Game that is being played in the uploaded video and is displayed under the video description.

Is there an API endpoint to set this Game title? Or do I have to `POST` to `https://www.youtube.com/metadata_ajax?action_edit_video=1` like the web UI does?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Youtube Data API` does not have this implemented at this time of writing. And nether we are able to `Get` the game title as well.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. I hope this gets added soon.

Comment: I would love to see Google implement this as well. Very much needed for what we're trying to do.

Comment: I asked this 2 years ago and they never replied to me XD https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35177425